# ListContourPlot3D drops data

Tags: plotting

I've generated an array of datapoints depending on three Variables and need to plot them in a comprehensive way. Easier than dividing the data into subplots of fixed variables, `ListContourPlot3D` seems ideal, but when I give it my data, the plot is only a fracture of what it ought to be.

Some of the data plus what it looks like with `ListContourPlot3D` follow:

```
data = {{0., 0.6, 0.1, 9.02376}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 8.93916}, {0.2, 0.6, 
0.1, 8.80622}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 8.65599}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 
8.49005}, {0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 8.30524}, {0., 0.6, 0.125, 
9.36876}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.125, 9.2633}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.125, 
9.10647}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.125, 8.92603}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.125, 
8.72415}, {0.5, 0.6, 0.125, 8.49606}, {0., 0.6, 0.15, 
9.69016}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.15, 9.56779}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.15, 
9.39245}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.15, 9.18576}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.15, 
8.95025}, {0.5, 0.6, 0.15, 8.68054}, {0., 0.6, 0.175, 
9.99355}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.175, 9.85979}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.175, 
9.66627}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.175, 9.43681}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.175, 
9.17087}, {0.5, 0.6, 0.175, 8.85835}, {0., 0.6, 0.2, 
10.288}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 10.1382}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 9.92939}, {0.3,
 0.6, 0.2, 9.68042}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 9.38528}, {0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 
9.03451}, {0., 0.65, 0.1, 14.0645}, {0.1, 0.65, 0.1, 
13.9296}, {0.2, 0.65, 0.1, 13.7189}, {0.3, 0.65, 0.1, 
13.4791}, {0.4, 0.65, 0.1, 13.2114}, {0.5, 0.65, 0.1, 
12.9109}, {0., 0.65, 0.125, 14.5799}, {0.1, 0.65, 0.125, 
14.42}, {0.2, 0.65, 0.125, 14.1798}, {0.3, 0.65, 0.125, 
13.8999}, {0.4, 0.65, 0.125, 13.5808}, {0.5, 0.65, 0.125, 
13.2154}, {0., 0.65, 0.15, 15.0401}, {0.1, 0.65, 0.15, 
14.8655}, {0.2, 0.65, 0.15, 14.6062}, {0.3, 0.65, 0.15, 
14.2938}, {0.4, 0.65, 0.15, 13.931}, {0.5, 0.65, 0.15, 
13.5054}, {0., 0.65, 0.175, 15.4499}, {0.1, 0.65, 0.175, 
15.2701}, {0.2, 0.65, 0.175, 14.9995}, {0.3, 0.65, 0.175, 
14.667}, {0.4, 0.65, 0.175, 14.2631}, {0.5, 0.65, 0.175, 
13.7835}, {0., 0.65, 0.2, 15.8229}, {0.1, 0.65, 0.2, 
15.6382}, {0.2, 0.65, 0.2, 15.3644}, {0.3, 0.65, 0.2, 
15.0176}, {0.4, 0.65, 0.2, 14.5846}, {0.5, 0.65, 0.2, 
14.0517}, {0., 0.7, 0.1, 22.4445}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 22.2317}, {0.2,
 0.7, 0.1, 21.8923}, {0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 21.5039}, {0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 
21.0666}, {0.5, 0.7, 0.1, 20.5716}, {0., 0.7, 0.125, 
23.1974}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.125, 22.9468}, {0.2, 0.7, 0.125, 
22.5688}, {0.3, 0.7, 0.125, 22.1247}, {0.4, 0.7, 0.125, 
21.6122}, {0.5, 0.7, 0.125, 21.018}, {0., 0.7, 0.15, 
23.829}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.15, 23.5723}, {0.2, 0.7, 0.15, 
23.1775}, {0.3, 0.7, 0.15, 22.6952}, {0.4, 0.7, 0.15, 
22.1217}, {0.5, 0.7, 0.15, 21.4387}, {0., 0.7, 0.175, 
24.3628}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.175, 24.113}, {0.2, 0.7, 0.175, 
23.7226}, {0.3, 0.7, 0.175, 23.2226}, {0.4, 0.7, 0.175, 
22.6006}, {0.5, 0.7, 0.175, 21.8388}};
```

Then the plot:

```
ListContourPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {{0., 0.5}, {.6, .7}, {.1, .2}},
    DataRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {.6, .7}, {.1, .2}}, Contours -> 9,
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesLabel -> {"r", "l", "w"}]
```

[image: Output of ListContourPlot3D]

Comment: This is not so difficult `ListPlot3D[#[[All, 2 ;;]] & /@ GatherBy[data, #[[1]] &],  
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]`.

Comment: The data you present is pretty coarse-grained, which may make it difficult to present and interpret a 3D contour plot. Since you seem to be able to generate your data from calculations, have you tried to calculate a much more fine-grained set? Alternatively, have you tried increasing the number of contour lines you requested?

Comment: @b.gatessucks thanks, that made a different chapter of the analysis much shorter, but here i'm trying to have the first three variables be the axes and the (ungatherable) 4th value make up the contours.

Comment: @MarcoB it's a FE Computation, so I could of course generate finer data, but that up there is just only about half the points to keep the post readable, also, those that i have took over 30 hours to generate, and i'd like to be done with this assignment by the end of the week ;-)

Comment: OK, so have you tried to increase the number of contours requested? Did that make any difference?

Comment: @MarcoB I have, also using the full data in this image, but the graph still exists only in a  small area of the overall parameter ranges. ![image](http://i.imgur.com/PLCiYZe.png)

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if a representation such as the following might help you to present your data:

```
ListSliceContourPlot3D[
 data, {"YStackedPlanes", 10},
 ContourShading -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]],
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {"r", "l", "w"}),
 ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One of my favorite new functions. Of course, I wanted to rotate it, but being a static image ... +1, btw.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but pretty neat!